# Python itertools tee, clones and caching

Tags: python, python-itertools

Assumed: When using the python `itertools.tee()`, all duplicate iterators refer to the original iterator, and the original is cached to improve performance.

My main concern in the following inquiry is regarding MY IDEA of **intended/proper caching behavior**. 
Edit: my idea of **proper caching** was based on flawed functional assumptions. Will ultimately need a little wrapper around tee (which will probably have consequences regarding caching).

---

## Question:

Lets say I create 3 iterator clones using tee: `a, b, c = itertools.tee(myiter,3)`. Also assume that at this point, I remove all references to the original, `myiter` (meaning, there is no great way for my code to refer back to the original hereafter).

At some later point in code, if I decided that I want another clone of `myiter`, can I just re-tee() one of my duplicates? (with proper caching back to the originally cached `myiter`)

In other words, at some later point, I *wish* I had instead used this: 
`a, b, c, d = itertools.tee(myiter,4)`. 
But, since I have discarded all references to the original `myiter`, the best I can muster would be:
`copytee = itertools.tee(a, 1) #where 'a' is from a previous tee()`

Does tee() know what I want here? (that I REALLY want to create a clone based on the original `myiter`, NOT the intermediate clone `a` (which may be partially consumed))

Comment: Did you try doing that? If it didn't work please give the error message are the behaviour encountered as well.

Comment: My iterator is functioning properly, But I cannot confirm whether or not the caching is carrying over to the second-hand clone. I plan to use this on a huge iterator, and want to make sure I am doing this properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing magical about `tee`.  It's just clever ;-)  At *any* point, `tee` clones the iterator passed to it.  That means the cloned iterator(s) will yield the values produced by the passed-in iterator *from this point on*.  But it's impossible for them to reproduce values that *were* produced *before* `tee` was invoked.

Let's show it with something much simpler than your example:

```
>>> it = iter(range(5))
>>> next(it)
0
```

0 is gone now - forever.  `tee()` can't get it back:

```
>>> a, b = tee(it)
>>> next(a)
1
```

So `a` pushed `it` to produce its next value.  It's that value that gets cached, so that other clones can reproduce it too:

```
>>> next(b)
1
```

To get that result, `it` wasn't touched - 1 was retrieved from the internal cache.  And now that all of `it`, `a` and `b` have produced 1, 1 is gone forever too.

I don't know whether that answers your question - answering "Does tee() know what I want here?" seems to require telepathy ;-)  That is, I don't know what you mean by "with proper caching".  It would be most helpful if you gave an exact example of the input/output behavior you're hoping for.

Short of that, the Python docs give Python code that's equivalent to tee(), and perhaps studying that would answer your question:

```
def tee(iterable, n=2):
    it = iter(iterable)
    deques = [collections.deque() for i in range(n)]
    def gen(mydeque):
        while True:
            if not mydeque:             # when the local deque is empty
                newval = next(it)       # fetch a new value and
                for d in deques:        # load it to all the deques
                    d.append(newval)
            yield mydeque.popleft()
    return tuple(gen(d) for d in deques)
```

You can see from that, for example, that nothing about an iterator's internal state is cached - all that's cached is the values produced *by* the passed-in iterator, starting from the time `tee()` is called.  Each clone has its own `deque` (FIFO list) of the passed-in iterator's values produced so far, and that's all the clones know about the passed-in iterator.  So it may be too simple for whatever you're really hoping for.

Comment: A 2nd-hand clone knows nothing about the original iterator. It will only produce the values produced by the 1st-hand iterator - & you must not use the 1st-hand iterator again! Just like you shouldn't use `it` again after making 1st-hand `tee(it)` clones. And there is no "original iter deque" anyway - there is one deque *per clone*, all independent of each other. I'm sorry, but I'm still quite unclear on what "properly cached" means to you. Give an exact desired input/output example or give up on that ;-)

Comment: Your final example shed much light on the issue. My idea of proper caching would be: cloning a clone, where the new deque referenced the original iter deque. It seems to be clear that, this doesn't happen...directly at least. As long as my 1st-hand clone has not consumed its values, 2nd-hand will essentially be properly cached. If there has been any consumption on the 1st-hand iter, any clones made from it thereafter, would not properly reflect the original iter (rather, the partially consumed 1st-hand).

Comment: sorry about repost. You have answered the issue for me. My idea of **proper caching** really needs a new topic.

Comment: If you can give an exact input/output example of desired behavior, perhaps it will be easy enough to write `tee-like` function that does what you want.

Comment: tee-like is exactly what I had in mind for new topic. I'm lucky right now that my code is setting up all of the tee's before any consumption. Probably would have been a nice little bug later if I hadn't realized how important that actually is (for my functionality).